# Fallo al registrar DLL

Tags: visual-studio, vba, dll

Necesito crear una DLL para acelerar un proceso realizado desde VBA en Word, que consume mucho tiempo con documentos extensos.
Para empezar a familiarizarme con la creación y uso de DLL estoy intentando realizar una
prueba programando en Visual Studio algo tan sencillo como

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Function Sumar(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
        Return a + b
    End Function
```

Lo compilo sin errores, pero al intentar registrar la DLL con regasm da el error

```
"RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No se registró ningún tipo"
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: En c#, ese error se daría si la clase no tiene un constructor default. No sé si eso se traslada igual a vba.

Comment: Y lo compilas como que?? biblioteca de clases??

Comment: @jachguate. No se si la clase tiene un constructor defatul.

Comment: @gbianchi: sí, como biblioteca de clases

Comment: Y porque la queres registrar??? en que la programaste???

Comment: @gbianchi: la programé en Visual Studio, y la quiero registrar porque para llamarla desde VBA entiendo que es necesario, ¿no?

Comment: visual studio es una ide... en que la programaste? en vb.net? en que version?  no estoy totalmente seguro de que todas las clases de .net se registren..

Comment: @gbianchi: sí, en vb.net. Es Visual Studio 2022, Versión 17.9.3.

Comment: no, a ver.. esa es la version de la ide. nada que ver, con lo que estas programando.. empeza por aprender a diferencia la ide, del lenguaje y version en la cual programas.. podes estar en la version de la ide que quieras, y progamar en .net 3, .net 5, core 6 o lo que sea.. otra vez, te vuelvo a preguntar, en que version estas programando.. no todas son registrables como vos pensas, por eso...

Comment: @gbianchi: disculpa, la versión es .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: No agregaste nada, ni un comvisible ni ninguna anotacion, no? tenes que agregar varias cosas para que la dll sea registrable, te fijaste en google todos los pasos que tenes que hacer? si tu clase es esa que mostras, le faltan muchas cosas...

Comment: @gbianchi: No agregue nada, no. Y elegí esa clase porque venía por defecto en la ide, pero si hay otras con las que el registro es más fácil no tengo inconveniente en cambiar. Perdona el off-topic: ¿cómo se envían aquí mensajes privados, si es que se puede? La razón es solicitar asesoramiento profesional sobre este asunto, porque no se si hacerlo aquí incumple la etiqueta

Comment: Aqui no existen los mensajes privados. Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Para que tu clase sea registrable y visible como dll para lo que queres hacer, tenes que decorarla y hacerle varias cosas. No es simplemente escribirla. Toda la info, esta en google, ya que es largo y son varias cosas las que tenes que hacer.

Comment: @gbianchi Investigaré. Gracias

Comment: me hicieron notar, que no existe un canal privado, pero publicamente hay un [chat]